# How to write a struct to file in C++ and read the file?

Tags: c++, buffer, readfile

I have a struct and write it to a file using the write().

```
struct PointFull {
    double lat;
    double lon;
};

PointFull item;
void* buffer = malloc(sizeof (item));
int fd = open("output", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);
if (fd < 0) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return 1;
}
memcpy(buffer, &item, sizeof (item));
write(fd2, buffer, sizeof (item));
```

Now I have a file named "output" in hard disk and then I want read the file to test data.

```
int fd2 = open("output", O_RDONLY, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);
if (fd2 < 0) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return 1;
}
void* bufferRead;
bufferRead = malloc(100);
read(fd2, bufferRead,100);
```

At the moment, I have bufferRead but I dont know how to read buffer to insert data to struct?

Comment: You can read or write directly to or from `item`, no need to go through an intermediate buffer.

Comment: First, I don't think there are many, if any legitimate use cases for `malloc` in c++.

Comment: Do you want to learn C or C++?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I know of one. If the allocation fails, `malloc` returns a NULL pointer, which is very easy to test; guarding against a failed constructor is much more trouble.

Comment: @Beta Cool. Couldn't you just catch the exception from `new` though? I don't think the handling would be that much more complicated.

Comment: I want to learn both of C and C++. I want to get the best performent.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: As I understand it, `new` doesn't throw an exception, the constructor *might*. The author of the constructor may have neglected to put that in, or been prevented by the design.

Comment: @Beta Can't `new` throw a `bad_alloc`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Hmm... You appear to be right. I'll have to reexamine my position on `malloc`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: How can I write directly from item to file?

Comment: `write(fd2, &item, sizeof (item));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You'd rather allocate a buffer of size `sizeof(PointFull)`. Because if  size of struct would ever be changed and become bigger than your hardcoded size, then you going to get a bug.
2. Use a local buffer unless you really need to use a dynamic memory. I assume that in your code you don't really need an allocation. It's just that you may easily forget to deallocate the memory, whereas buffer deleted automagically when a function returns.

```
int fd2 = open("output", O_RDONLY, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);
if (fd2 < 0) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return 1;
}
char bufferRead[sizeof(PointFull)];
read(fd2, bufferRead, sizeof(bufferRead));
//Now as you've read it, just cast the memory to struct, and assign it
item = *reinterpret_cast<PointFull*>(bufferRead);
//okay, now item holds the file content, you no longer need the buffer
```

Also note: your struct might be aligned by inserting a padding. Although I don't think it would be the case with PointFull, anyway, when you need to serialize structures like here, you'd better declare it with `#pragma pack` to not allow the padding. E.g.:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // exact fit - no padding
struct PointFull {
    double lat;
    double lon;
};
#pragma pack(pop) //back to whatever the previous packing mode was
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you have tagged C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct PointFull {
    double lat;
    double lon;

    PointFull(double lat_in = 0, double lon_in = 0) 
        : lat(lat_in), lon(lon_in) {}
};

int main() {
    PointFull item(123123, 123123);

    cout << "Writing to disk" << endl;
    ofstream fout("saved_point.txt");
    fout << item.lat << ' ' << item.lon;
    fout.close();

    cout << "Reading from disk" << endl;
    PointFull item_from_disk;
    ifstream fin("saved_point.txt");
    fin >> item_from_disk.lat >> item_from_disk.lon;
    fin.close();

    cout << "From RAM and then disk" << endl;
    cout << item.lat << ' ' << item.lon << endl;
    cout << item_from_disk.lat << ' ' << item_from_disk.lon << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is different between using fd and ofstream. I think fd is faster. If I still use buffer, how to read data from a buffer?

Comment: This is not a good solution when my struct has 100 members...

Answer (score 2):

- You can use fwrite and fread to write data into file and read from file.
  Below is sample code for same.

  ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   struct PointFull
   {
      int number;
      char text[10];
      double real_number;
   };

   int main()
  {
   struct PointFull  data = {1, "Hello!", 3.14159}, read_data;
   FILE *fout = fopen("file_path", "w");
   fwrite(&data, sizeof(PointFull ), 1, fout);
   //   fprintf(fout, "%d %s %f",data.number, data.text, data.real_number);
   fclose(fout);

   FILE* fin = fopen("file_path", "r");
   fread(&read_data, sizeof(PointFull ), 1, fin);
   printf("%d %s %lf\n", read_data.number, read_data.text, read_data.real_number);
   fclose(fin);
   return 0;
  }
  ```

  - If u use fwrite data will be written in binary or ascii format.To read that data u have to use fread.
  - If u use fprintf and fscanf ,data will be stored in human redable format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your way is easier to do but I wonder using write and read with fd is faster than using fread fwrite?

Comment: @MaiNhậtTân it's a question of portability vs safety. See: `fwrite()` supported in any platform since it is part of a standard; but `write()` isn't. On the other hand the C-api like `fwrite()` uses pointers, hence you're potentially in the danger of a nullptr-reference somewhere, which would lead to a crash. Posix functions like `write()` have no such a problem.

Answer (score -1):

There's an MIT library called '[drake](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__yaml__serialization.html)' that has this functionality. You've got to take some steps to serialize the structure but their documentation seems pretty good!

Comment: I don't think this answers this question. not my downvote, but if I had more to give, I'd add one.